# Why sem_open return always same addres

Tags: c++, ipc, semaphore

I am using semaphore to synchronize 2 processes.
I create a thread that fork a process and wait for it to finish, could be more than one thread.

My problem is that every thread point always at the same semaphore though I open it with different name.

This is an example:

```
sem_t * sem_test = sem_open("test", O_CREAT, 0600, 0);
sem_t * sem_test2 = sem_open("test2", O_CREAT, 0600, 0);

std::cout << sem_test << std::endl;
std::cout << sem_test2 << std::endl;
try{
    sem_wait(sem_test);
}
catch (const std::system_error& e) {
    std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
    std::cout << e.code() << '\n';
}
```

It will print the same address for both `sem_test` and `sem_test2`

Reading the documentation I didn't find an explanation or I missing it.
Is it the normal behavior? If not how to fix it?

It will fail when try to do `sem_wait` on the second thread while the first thread freed its semaphore.

I am working on Raspberry Pi4 with official Raspian dist.

-Edit:

As suggested I tried with initial "/" on semaphore name and test if `sem_open` returns in error.

```
sem_t * sem_test = sem_open("/test", O_CREAT, 0600, 0);
sem_t * sem_test2 = sem_open("/test1", O_CREAT, 0600, 0);

    if(sem_test == SEM_FAILED){
        std::cout << "FAIL TO OPEN TEST" << std::endl;
    }

    if(sem_test2 == SEM_FAILED){
        std::cout << "FAIL TO OPEN TEST2" << std::endl;
    }
    
    std::cout << sem_test << std::endl;
    std::cout << sem_test2 << std::endl;
    sem_wait(sem_test);
```

The result is the same.

Comment: What values are being returned?  Are you sure they're not error codes, e.g. SEM_FAILED? - https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_open.3.html

Comment: Most likely, yes, since `sem_open` man page helpfully directs you to the `sem_overview` manual page, and the `sem_overview` manual page helpfully informs you that the semaphore names must start with a slash.

Comment: AFAIK `sem_wait` doesn't throw an exception if it fails, unless you are using some special C++ wrapper for it.  Basically no Unix system calls do, as they are designed for C rather than C++.  As @Den-Jason for `sem_open`, you have to check the return value instead.

Comment: There are no errors when create semaphore and I tried name with / but didn't change. 
Everything work fine if I don't destroy the first sempahore in the first thread.

Comment: Please show us the exact output of your updated program.

Comment: My guess is that the problem is not in the code you are showing us. Please provide a [mre] (including the function `main` and all included headers).